# What's the difference between 'err@(Left _)' and 'Left err'

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, haskell

I'm trying the codes from <Real World Haskell>.

On GHC version 6.10.4:

```
data ParseState = ParseState {
  string :: String
} deriving (Show)

newtype Parse a = Parse {
  runParse :: ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState)
}

parse :: Parse a -> String -> Either String a
parse parser initState =
  case runParse parser (ParseState initState) of
    Left err          -> Left err
    Right (result, _) -> Right result
```

Everything went fine until I changed 'Left err' to 'err@(Left _)':

```
--  err@(Left _)      -> err
{-
 -  Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
 -    a = (a, ParseState)
 -  When generalising the type(s) for `parse'
-}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is subtle.  The `case` is scrutinizing a value of type `Either String (a, ParseState)`, so when you name the pattern in

```
err@(Left _) -> err
```

`err` has that same type. However, the function's return type says it should be an `Either String a`, which doesn't match `err`'s type of `Either String (a, ParseState)`.  Looking at the type of `Left`:

```
Left :: x -> Either x y
```

When you use `Left` in the right-hand side in

```
Left err -> Left err
```

You are giving it a chance to choose a different `y`, namely `a` instead of `(a, ParseState)`.

So even though the *values* are the same, the *types* are not, and so they can't be substituted.

By the way, there are a few very handy functions for your case in `Control.Arrow` (specializing to `(->)` for simplicity):

```
left :: (a -> a') -> Either a b -> Either a' b
right :: (b -> b') -> Either a b -> Either a b'
(+++) :: (a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> Either a b -> Either a' b'
```

whose semantics are fixed by the free theorems (read: they only have one reasonable implementation, so they do what you'd expect from their types).  So you could write your code as:

```
parse parser = right fst . runParse parser . ParseState
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just following the book. I'll make a mental note for Control.Arrow and come back later. Regarding your answer to my question, it makes sense for me. But do you think the compiler should be made more clever to be aware that err in 'err@(Left _)' has been pattern matched to a Left data constructor?

Comment: No I don't think it should be more clever.  This is just one of the subtleties of the type system, but it is consistent.  A type system that could recognize such things probably exists (GADTs are on the way there), but it is more complicated to implement and probably has more subtleties in usage elsewhere to make up for it.  Hindley-Milner is a nice point of balance.

Comment: Is there a mistake in the type of (+++)?  Shouldn't it be
   (+++) :: (a->a') -> (b->b') -> Either a b -> Either a' b'